# Quine "Methods of Logic" chapter 14 – Categorical Statements

Tags: logic

I am trying to teach myself some mathematical logic with no mathematical background.

I was wondering if someone would be kind enough to help me with these exercises from Quine's *Methods of Logic*. I'm sure I have made plenty of mistakes and would be very happy to receive correction.

The matter concerns categorical statements, which as is well known, come in 4 forms

**A** (Universal Affirmative): All *F* are *G*

**E** (Universal Negative): No *F* are *G*

**I** (Particular Affirmative): Some F are G

**O** (Particular Negative): Some F are not G

Here is the exercise portion:
"Classify the following statements as between **A**, **E**, **I**, or **O**, and specify in each case which terms correspond to 'F' and which to 'G'"

1. "Blessed are the meek"

My answer: **A**, where *F* = the meek and *G* = the blessed

2. "All that glisters is not gold"

My answer: **I** (Not all, i.e. some of what glitters = *F*
and *G* = what is gold)
or is it **E**?

3. "There is no God but Allah"

My answer: **A** where *F* is the Gods, and *G* is Allah

4. "Hope springs eternal"

My answer: I'm honestly not sure. **A**? **I**? Can someone help me formulate this as an F, G statement?

5. "The rule applies to everyone"

My answer: **A**, where *F*= everyone and *G*= people the rule applies to

6. "We should all be happy as kings"

My answer: **A**, where *F*= people that are kings and G= people that are happy

7. "A policeman's lot is not a happy one"

My answer: **O**, where *F*= people that are policemen, and G= people that are happy

8. "There are smiles that make you blue"

My answer: **I**, where *F*= some smiles and *G*= things that make you blue

9. "I journeyed hither a Boeotian road"

My answer: I'm stumped. **I**? where *F*= journeys I took and *G* = times I went down a Boeotian road?

10. "I was stopped by the door of a tomb"

My answer: I'm stumped. **I**? Can someone help me formulate this as a *F,G* statement

Comment: 1. correct. 2. maybe it is a little bit ambiguous; usually it is ""Not all that glisters is gold" and thus is **O**: "Some that glitters is not gold". 4. maybe, we can read as "All hope is eternal". 9. and 10. are terrible... Maybe 10 is "Everything that stopped me is the door of a tomb"???